# Issue with Logstash

Tags: logstash

I am setting up log stash forwarder instead of shipper and in the due process i had to make changes to the indexer side. But after making changes at indexer side to use lumberjack i am not able to start the indexer and it throws the below error

**{:timestamp=>"2014-07-24T19:18:47.026000+0000", :message=>"Using milestone 1 input plugin 'lumberjack'. This plugin should work, but would benefit from use by folks lik
e you. Please let us know if you find bugs or have suggestions on how to improve this plugin.  For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1
.4.2-modified/plugin-milestones", :level=>:warn}
{:timestamp=>"2014-07-24T19:18:57.383000+0000", :message=>"+---------------------------------------------------------+\n| An unexpected error occurred. This is probably
 a bug.   |\n| You can find help with this problem in a few places:    |\n|                                                         |\n| * chat: #logstash IRC channel o
n freenode irc.          |\n|     IRC via the web: http://goo.gl/TI4Ro                |\n| * email: logstash-users@googlegroups.com                |\n| * bug system: ht
tps://logstash.jira.com/                |\n|                                                         |\n+---------------------------------------------------------+\nThe
 error reported is: \n  Neither PUB key nor PRIV key:"}**

Below is the conf file which is at indexer side

```
input {
lumberjack {
  host => "abc"
  port => 5043
  type => "logs"
  ssl_certificate => "/etc/logstash/logstash-forwarder.crt"
  ssl_key => "/etc/logstash/logstash-forwarder.key"
}
}



output {
stdout { }
elasticsearch {
cluster => "abc"
}
}
```

Please let me know how can get rid of this error

Answer (score 0):

That's a Ruby error from OpenSSL, likely caused by an invalid SSL key file. I'd check the following discussions for clues as to what went wrong when you generated the SSL key:

[OpenSSL - Neither PUB key nor PRIV key:: nested asn1 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391312/openssl-neither-pub-key-nor-priv-key-nested-asn1-error)

[What causes "Neither PUB key nor PRIV key:: nested asn1 error" when building a public key in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293608/what-causes-neither-pub-key-nor-priv-key-nested-asn1-error-when-building-a-p)

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7074